# How to set custom header and footer content by using phantom package in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf-generation, phantomjs

Actually, I am working with generating pdf reports using phantom package in nodeJS. I've found that we can use phantom.callback method for setting it. But I have a problem that when this callback returns simple text it works fine, but when I try to use complicated function which use closures and jade engine for generating html I have error in phantom output that jade variable is not defined, I think this problem was occurred because callback which is mentioned about work in context of child phantom process, therefore all variables which are defined in my code in that callback don't work. So, how can I solve this issue? Maybe you know better phantomJS wrapper for doing this stuff?
I use this package `phantom": "0.7.x"`

```
//there I define all varaibles (jade, fs, etc., so I am sure that they are correct)

function generatePage(_page, reportConfig, phantom, html, report) {
    _page.set('viewportSize', reportConfig.viewportSize);
    var config = _.extend(reportConfig.paperSize, {
            header: {
                height: "2cm",
                //contents: phantom.callback(headerCallback)
                contents: phantom.callback(function (pageNum, numPages) {
                    var fn = jade.compile(headerTemplate); //Jade in undefined in phantom stdout
                    var templateData = _.extend({ currentPage: pageNum, numberPages: numPages }, report);
                    var generatedHtml = fn(templateData);
                    return "<h1>HEADER</h1><br />" /*+ generatedHtml*/;
                })
            }
            , footer: {
                height: "1cm",
                contents: phantom.callback(function (pageNum, numPages) {
                    return "<p>Page " + pageNum + " of " + numPages + "</p>"; //WORKS fine
                })
            }
        }
    );
    _page.set('paperSize', config);
    _page.setContent(html);
    return _page;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the wrapper. The function that you pass into `phantom.callback` will be executed in the page context (in the phantomjs engine). So, if you cannot inject jade into the page itself (I don't know I'm not familiar with it) so that the template can be compile in the page context, then you simply cannot use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phantom callback doesn't work this way, the function you are sending as callback will be stringified and recompiled in the phantom context where your dependencies will be unknown.

Is a late answer but i didn't find anything like this out there in the wild. So maybe will help others.

You have to generate the html out of the page context, right after you define jade and others, and compile the result into a function which you'll send as callback:

```js
//there I define all varaibles (jade, fs, etc., so I am sure that they are correct)
var fn = jade.compile(headerTemplate); //Jade is undefined in phantom context
var templateData = report;
var generatedHtml = fn(templateData);
//You can use some patterns in your template for pageNum and numPages like #pageNum# and replace them after compilation.
//here you are compiling the result into a function which you will send 
//as callback(you have to remove all spaces and all breaklines to avoid compilation errors)
var headerCallbak = 'function(pageNum, numPages) { var x = \''+ generatedHtml .trim().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") +'\'; return x.relpace("#pageNumber#", pageNum).replace("#numPages#",numPages);}';

function generatePage(_page, reportConfig, phantom, html, report) {
    _page.set('viewportSize', reportConfig.viewportSize);
    var config = _.extend(reportConfig.paperSize, {
            header: {
                height: "2cm",
                contents: phantom.callback(headerCallbak)
            }
            , footer: {
                height: "1cm",
                contents: phantom.callback(function (pageNum, numPages) {
                    return "<p>Page " + pageNum + " of " + numPages + "</p>"; //WORKS fine
                })
            }
        }
    );
    _page.set('paperSize', config);
    _page.setContent(html);
    return _page;
}
```

Comment: Could you say, can we use phantom.callback with anonymous function to "height" attribute, not no "contents" only?